# Interfaces in .Net

Tags: .net, vb.net, class, interface, io

I would like to use the same code for copying files to an FTP server, and through USB. I've already written some code, which as of now uses functions from the `System.IO` namespace.

To minimize code duplication, I've listed the functions which I need from the system.IO namespace, and I was thinking of designing an interface exposing similar functions, and then two classes, one for FTP file operations, and one for local ones.

I have a few questions about Interfaces though:

1. Could design my interface so that the `File.*` and `Directory.*` organisation be preserved (so that routines declared in the interface follow the same hierarchy than in the IO namespace)?
2. Is there a way, for local operations, to just map functions from the IO namespace to the corresponding interface functions (writing something like `Sub IO.File.Delete Implements IOInterface.File_Delete`)?
3. Can I declare something like `Dim IOHandler As IOInterface`, assuming that `IOInterface` is the name of my interface? Can I then write both `IOHandler = New LocalIOHandler` and `IOHandler = New FTPIOHandler`, assuming `LocalIOHandler` and `FTPIOHandler` are my two classes implementing the `IOInterface`?

Thanks!
CFP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change an existing class so that it implements your own interface. You can however design your own interface where your methods return classes that already exist - like the ones in the System.IO namespace.

You can also implement your own class that wraps the System.IO classes so that your IOInterface.Delete maps to a FileInfo.Delete (please forgive the C# syntax, my VB is rusty):

```
public class MyFileClass : IOInterface
{
  public void DeleteFile(string fileName) 
  {
     new FileInfo(fileName).Delete();
  }
}
```

In response to #3:
Yes. A variable of type IOInterface can hold any type that implements that interface. You can also later cast it to the specific type if you need to.

Comment: Though not incorrect the downcast should be avoided and concidered a smell.

Comment: Agreed, but sometimes it is necessary and it is important to know that the stored object is still of the implementation type not only of the interface type.

Comment: So people keep telling me :) but they are also almost all of them out of good examples of when. That said I Think you were right in mentioning the possibility here since it seems OP i very new to oo

Answer (score 1):

I can't help you with the first one i simply don't get what you mean with function hierachi but for the other two. No there's no syntax for that you'll have to implement a method that forwards the Call to the method. E.g. (pseudo cod I haven't written VB for years)

```
Sub open(path as string)
  Begin
    Return File.Open path
  End
```

For your 3rd you could say that that's the point (it's not the only point) of interfaces that the consuming code does not need to know the concrete type

Comment: I meant that in my interface I would define specify the need to have to child namespaces, File and Directory, which would hold the functions to respectively delete, create, etc; a file or a directory, as is done in the IO Namespace.

Comment: An interface resides in a namespace but can specify no limitations to which namespace declaring class lives in. Further File and Directory are _classes_ in the namespace System.IO.

Comment: So is there a way to have sort of subclasses in a directory?

Comment: I don't know what you mean with subclasses in a directory. There's no directories in the code (except for the class called directory). It's possible to have classes in classes

Comment: Woops, I'm tired. I mean, can an interface declare classes and subclasses? (So that implementations have to implement two classes, Directory And File (Then it would seem as though System.IO implements that interface)

Comment: You can _only_ declare what a class that implements the interface needs to implment when it comes to methods, properties and events. There's no way you can specify that a class needs to implement a class. The reason is simple a class cannot implement a class. It's true you can _declare a class inside another class but that's very different. Further what you describe sounds like an implementations detail and those should be kept hidden not something you require